# Access class member "directly" like std::string

Tags: c++, class

I would like the following code to be equivalent:

```
f = "abc";
h.data = f;
```

---

**EDIT:** I'd also like the ability to do the following:

```
f += "def"; // f.data == "abcdef";
std::string s = f; // s = "abcdef";

std::cout << f << std::endl;
std::cin >> f;

std::vector<std::string> v (f);
v.push_back(h);

// This would be overkill.
printf("%s", (f + std::string("...\n")).c_str());
```

Would I need to "inherit" `std::string` or something? (I'm new to this stuff, so could you show me how?)

---

Here's my class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    std::string data;
} f, h;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: I'd also like the ability to do the following: [...]

[ This would have been better served as a new question but I don't think you could have foreseen that. ]

No, you don't need to inherit from `std::string`. One possible way to do what you want is to add a conversion operator. (I won't address how to implement `operator+=`, it can be looked up elsewhere.)

```
class foo {
    std::string data;
public:
    foo&
    operator=(std::string); // See Kerrek's answer for implementation

    operator std::string const&() const
    { return data; }
};
```

This will do what you want. **But** I strongly advise you not to use that. Surprising implicit conversions are frowned upon; I recommend reading [Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/019.htm) to learn why.

Alternatively you can make the conversion operator `explicit` (as in, declaring it `explicit operator std::string const&() const;`) to suppress implicit conversions. But that's quite less convenient and readable than adding a member function with an appropriate name:

```
class foo {
    // as before

    operator std::string const&() const
    { return as_string(); }

    std::string const&
    as_string() const
    { return data; }
};

foo f;

// Contrast the uses:
// std::string s0 = f; Not ok; would be an implicit conversion
std::string s0(f); // Ok; explicit conversion
std::string s1 = f.as_string(); // Ok; std::string s1(f.as_string()) works too

std::vector<std::string> v;
// v.push_back(f); Not ok; would use an implicit conversion
v.push_back(static_cast<std::string const&>(f)); // Ok; inconvenient
v.push_back(f.as_string()); // Ok; convenient
```

Whatever you choose, I still recommend implementing appropriate operators for working with streams:

```
std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, foo const& f)
{
    return os << f.as_string();
}

std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& is, foo& f)
{
    std::string extracted;
    if(is >> extracted) {
        f = std::move(extracted);
    }
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Add an assignment operator:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    std::string data;
    Foo & operator=(const std::string & s) { data = s; return *this; }
};
```

Depending on what you want to return you could also define it like this:

```
std::string & operator=(const std::string & s) { data = s; return data; }
```

Or even, in C++0x:

```
std::string & operator=(std::string s) { data = std::move(s); return data; }
```

The former lets you write: `Foo x, y; y = x = "hello";`. The latter lets you write: `std::string a, b; Foo x; a = x = b;`. Take your pick.

Comment: Any particular reason `operator=` is taking its argument by value?

Comment: @Ildjarn: I thought it might facilitate move semantics... though I should have added `data = std::move(s)` I guess. Or just take the argument by const reference.

Comment: @Kerrek - compiler cannot move lvalues, so you would have to `std::move` explicitly, which of course would preclude using pre-C++0x.

Comment: OK, I added C++98 and C++0x versions separately to avoid the confusion.

Comment: @muntoo: The answer is just a verbatim copy of the current answer replacing `=` with `+=`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to do:

```
Foo f;
f = "abc";
```

In which case, you will need to overload `operator=`.  Something along the lines of:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void operator= (const std::string &str) { data = str; }
    std::string data;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[Overload the `=` operator](http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the operator.

But I do subscribe to ESA rules about programming. Anything above the simple stuff (eg. I/O, strings, numbers, booleans) get the objects to have member functions. Makes the code more readable and maintainable.

See http://www.esa.int/TEC/Software_engineering_and_standardisation/TECRFBUXBQE_2.html